# wpf screen on different thread freezes 'randomly'

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpftoolkit

I have a problem which i have had for over a week now and I can't figure out why.

i have a waiting screen which I've placed in a different thread so it can load and show it's self even if the code is doing loads of work (when i did evrything in the same thread the screen wouldn't show it's self and i think that's because the code was to busy doing other stuff)

however it doesn't always freeze just some times and only on the tablet, it works fine on my pc (at least i have not noticed it freezing while testing it on my pc).

i've tried to 'hack' some workarounds in it, for example placing a cancel button on the waiting screen so it can be closed however it cannot be clicked (asif it freezes and doesn't respond)

1 time i also thought it was giving the problem because i would close it before the thread was started so i made a boolean which would say it if the thread was still loading or not if it was and i tried to close it i would add an event listner so it would be closed when the thread had finished starting up.

anyway here's the code, i do hope someone here can help me out.

```
public partial class WaitWindow : Window
{
    //private static WaitWindow ww = new WaitWindow();
    private static Thread thread;
    private static event ThreadStartingEvent started;
    private delegate void ThreadStartingEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public static bool disposable = false;

    private static bool startingThread;
    private static bool StartingThread
    {
        get
        {
            return startingThread;
        }
        set
        {
            startingThread = value;
            if (!startingThread && started != null)
            {
                started(null, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    // To refresh the UI immediately
    private delegate void RefreshDelegate();
    private static void Refresh(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        obj.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
            (RefreshDelegate)delegate { });
    }

    public WaitWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void BeginDisplay()
    {
        if (thread == null)
        {
            startingThread = true;
            thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                WaitWindow ww = new WaitWindow();
                ww.Show();


                ww.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                ww.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            startingThread = false;
        }
    }

    public static void EndDisplay()
    {
        if (startingThread)
        {
            started += new ThreadStartingEvent(WaitWindow_started);
        }
        if (thread != null)
        {
            disposable = false;
            thread.Abort();
            thread = null;
        }
    }

    static void WaitWindow_started(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.Abort();
        thread = null;
        started = null;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (disposable)
        {
            disposable = false;
            thread.Abort();
            thread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.WaitWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="WaitWindow" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Width="1024" Height="640">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:BusyIndicator Name="BusyBar" IsBusy="True" BusyContent="Even geduld a.u.b.">
        </xctk:BusyIndicator>
        <Button Name="button1" Width="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="550,271,0,0" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button1_Click">X</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

maby some extra info: when i am doing tasks which might take some time (getting data from a remote database) i call `BeginDisplay()` and when the code is done i call `EndDisplay()`
this seemed rather obvious to me but i suppose there's no harm in mentioning it.

EDIT:
i should probably mention i'm using .net framework 3.5

Comment: i'm not that good with cross threading, how would i make it so i can do ww.close() from the main thread (which is not the thread it was created on?)

Comment: @EliArbel i'm just going out on a limb here and assume .net framework 3.5 does not have the InovekAsync method since i'm getting an error saying it did not exist.
also a fail on my behalf not mentioning i'm using .net 3.5

Comment: it looks like this was the solution, but i'll need to test a bit more.
i've also encounterd an other error (only on tablet as well) which prevents me from testing any further atm but that's discussion for an other thread,
maby you should post it as an answer and i'll let you know if this was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing background asynchronous tasks you will need to create a SynchronizationContext. Perhaps this is the cause of the problem?

```
// Create a thread
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () =>
{
    // Create our context, and install it:
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    // When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
    tempWindow.Closed += (s,e) => 
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

    tempWindow.Show();
    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));

// Set the apartment state
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
// Make the thread a background thread
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
// Start the thread
newWindowThread.Start();
```

This code is pinched from [this blog article](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/), which is worth a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would move the processing that is locking the UI off to a background thread and keep the main thread free for all UI updates which you get back to by `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, so what you have here is a very different implementation.

The first thing that jumps out at me is the use of `Thread.Abort()` I'm pretty sure the MSDN documentation basically says don't use it unless your thread has no other means of stopping. In particular, if you have aborted the thread, what is going to be left around to close the open window. Could this be your problem?

Comment: None, instead let it close when the message pump `Dispatcher.Run()` finishes. In short follow the code that @James World has answered with.